# Stop Sequelize from modifying the schema

Tags: sequelize.js

Sequelize will automatically create tables, indexes, foreign key constraints, etc. when a model is updated (in my case with a Postgres database). There are a couple of options that affect this: sync.force and sync.alter. I have both of those set to false, but it's not enough -- what I would really like is to prevent Sequelize from modifying the schema in any way.

Is that possible?

Comment: The short answer, do not use `sync` method. Instead, try migrations.

Comment: Hi @Mr.R. I don't use the sync method explicitly. Will Sequelize invoke sync automatically? I'm using the Feathers framework, so perhaps it is invoking sync.